# click image with confidence python

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to build a macro for a game I play. I want to use pyautogui to find an image with `confidence=(0.2)` and then move the mouse to its position and click. I'm not sure what to do from here. It will find the image and print but when I try to add `pyautogui.click('forgedspirit.png')` I get an error: `cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object`.

```
def new_method():  
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('forgespirit.png', confidence=(0.2)) != None:
        print("I can see it.")
        pyautogui.click('forgespirit.png')
        time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        print("image not found")
        time.sleep(0.5)
new_method()
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that it's **not** exactly matched; if it was found with less than 1.0 confidence, the `pyautogui.click(name)` shortcut won't work because that needs to be an exact match. Why not assign the result of `locateOnScreen` and use that (if you're using Python 3.8 and up, you can do that as part of the conditional: `if (image := pyautogui.locateOnScreen(...)) is not None: ...`)?

Comment: I'm using python 3.7. I tried: forgespirit = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('forgespirit.png', confidence=(0.25))
def new_method():  
    while True:
        if forgespirit is not None:
            print("I can see it.")
            pyautogui.click(forgespirit)
            time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
            print("image not found")
            time.sleep(0.5)
new_method() But now it won't find the image.

Answer (score 2):

instead of telling pyautogui to click the image, you should tell it to click the coordinates of the image.
Try this:

```
try:
    pos = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('forgespirit.png', confidence=(0.2))
    if pos != None:
        print("I can see it.")
        pyautogui.click(pos[0], pos[1])
        time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        print("image not found")
        time.sleep(0.5)
except:
    print("image not found")
```